# Open recordset with OBDC tables, dbSeeChanges not working

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been struggling all day with running a loop through a recordset in MS Access 2010. I've been able to do this before, but never when the recordset is referencing the primary key. I've resolved the dbSeeChanges error, but it's still not working. Thanks for any advice, and happy Thanksgiving!

```
Private Sub Command26_Click()

    Dim Query As String
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim url1 As String
    Dim url3 As String
    Dim fullurl As String

    url1 = "http://arlenmusic.azurewebsites.net/access-event-musicians.php?
    event_musician_id="
    url3 = "&action=add"
    Query = "SELECT dbo_event_musician.job_number, 
    dbo_event_musician.event_musician_id, dbo_event_musician.sub_event_id, 
    dbo_event_musician.name, dbo_event_musician.instrument_key, 
    dbo_event_musician.set_up_time, dbo_event_musician.start_time, 
    dbo_event_musician.booked_until, dbo_event_musician.special_songs, 
    dbo_event_musician.attire, dbo_event_musician.include_status, 
    dbo_event_musician.sub, dbo_event_musician.status, dbo_event_musician.notes, 
    dbo_event_musician.date_entered from dbo_event_musician WHERE   
    (((dbo_event_musician.sub_event_id) Like [Forms]![event_scheduling]!
    [sub_event_selector])) ORDER BY dbo_event_musician.instrument_key;"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(Query, , dbSeeChanges)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        fullurl = url1 + rs!event_musician_id + url3    
        Application.FollowHyperlink (fullurl)         
        rs.MoveNext     
    Loop     

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing 
    Set db = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a good description of your problem

Comment: As @TimWilliams says, this leaves us with insufficient information. Your query has several columns that aren't used and has `dbo_` prefixes which makes me think you're reading a linked table to a SQL Server database. I also note that you omit the recordset type which most likely defaults to `dbOpenDynaset` when `dbOpenForwardOnly` would likely suffice. You also said you cannot do it with primary key. Is the primary key by any chance a `bigint`? If you open the linked table, do you see data?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I am home for the holiday but will try to shed some light. Yes, I am reading linked tables in a SQL Azure database. 'not working' means I am getting the dbSeeChanges error even though I plugged in that option. The primary key is just a five digit number. I will try dbOpenForwardOnly when I am back at the office on Monday. I have only been using VBA for 2 months so I apologize if I'm not sharing enough info.

Comment: And yes, data does populate in the linked table when I open it. Perhaps on Monday I will show you the code in the loop that does work and that will allow you to spot the difference.

Comment: Hi, @this, just an update. I changed the type parameter to dbOpenForwardOnly and got a new error message, too few parameters, expected 1.

Comment: Last thing...I know I I'm referencing way too many columns in the SQL statement, but I tired to shorten it and received the same error...

Comment: That error is a generic error which can be thrown whenever there are references to identifiers that don't exist. DAO will treat unresolved identifiers as a parameter, which is why you get that error. Double check your spelling of all columns & table names.

Comment: Thanks @this. So, this code is pulled directly from the Access query design builder, which, when run, fetches the records I'm looking for. So I know that it's not spelling or syntax. What I can tell you is that I have another loop through a recordset that does work. In my next two comments, I will post, first, a recordset that does work, and second, the recordset that does not work. Hopefully, with your skilled eye, you can spot a difference between the two that will point me in the right direction. My gut is that it has to do with the "Like" or criteria part of the statement.

Comment: This is a recordset that can be looped through "SELECT dbo_event_musician.name, musicians.[Email Address] FROM musicians INNER JOIN (dbo_event INNER JOIN dbo_event_musician ON dbo_event.job_number = dbo_event_musician.job_number) ON musicians.name = dbo_event_musician.name WHERE (((dbo_event.date) > Now())) GROUP BY dbo_event_musician.name, musicians.[Email Address];"

Comment: Here is the recordset that I am having trouble with. SELECT dbo_event_musician.event_musician_id, dbo_sub_event.sub_event_id
FROM dbo_sub_event LEFT JOIN dbo_event_musician ON dbo_sub_event.sub_event_id = dbo_event_musician.sub_event_id
WHERE (((dbo_sub_event.sub_event_id) Like [Forms]![event_scheduling]![sub_event_selector]));

Comment: The fundamental difference between the two is that the one that does work has a WHERE clause that is just based on the date, and the second one has a WHERE clause that is based on a selection in a listbox (yes, I made sure that something is selected in the listbox). I bet that has something do with it, but I don't know what!!

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it's actually not the `dbSeeChanges` that's the problem. Rather, it's that you are using Database.OpenRecordset, but it contains expression `[Forms]![event_scheduling]![sub_event_selector]`, which is foreign to DAO.

See, it works in Access because you are going through the Access layer and Access recognizes those expressions and resolve them for you. But when you're using DAO directly (e.g. `Database.Execute` or `Database.OpenRecordset`), you are in fact bypassing Access and thus not getting those expression resolved. DAO correctly recognizes those as unresolved identifier and gives you the "too few parameters" error.

One way to resolve this is to make use of `QueryDef.Parameters`, then perform an `OpenRecordset`.

Here's a sample untested aircode to illustrate the point.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef
qdf.SQL = "PARAMETERS [MyFirstParameter] TEXT, [MySecondParameter] LONG; SELECT a, b, c FROM myTable WHERE a = [MyFirstParameter] AND b = [MySecondParameter];"
qdf.Parameters("MyFirstParameter").Value = "abc"
qdf.Parameters("MySecondParameter").Value = 2
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

You can consult MSDN for more documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845640.aspx). The advantage of that approach is that you can specify what will be parameterized and how it should be resolved, then directly assign the value from where you were originally reading. That way you can avoid using fragile expressions like `Forms!MyForm!MyControl` which won't be validated until runtime and could give unexpected results.

The alternative is to wrap the expression in an `Eval()` which will allow it to work in both contexts but I really do not like that because it basically allows arbitrary code execution in SQL and I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Fascinating! Thanks for the thorough explanation. I thought that DAO was part of the ACE engine that Access uses to evaluate expressions, but now I understand that that's not the case. Now that I understand the problem, I think I will rewrite the query to avoid the problem expression.

Comment: Oh wait, if I want to try your workaround Eval(), I need to rewrite the SQL Query as an expression, right? Eval() takes an expression, not a query. Can you help me with that @this? I'm a drag and drop guy and don't know the syntax well enough to figure this out on my own.

Comment: No, you simply wrap the expressions like `Forms!MyForm!MyControl` inside the `Eval()` _inside_ the SQL query statement, similar to this snippet.... `... dbo_event_musician.sub_event_id) Like Eval([Forms]![event_scheduling]!
    [sub_event_selector]) ...`. Then it will work whenever you open it from UI or running it in the code with `Database.OpenRecordset`

Comment: Eureka! The problem is solved :) Right now I'm using the Eval() as a place holder until I can reverse engineer the code with QueryDef.Parameters.

Comment: would you be willing to provide me with your email address so that I can reach out to you directly with any issues/freelance work? You were so incredibly responsive and helpful...i'd like to keep up this relationship!